# AWK, can't match regex

Tags: regex, bash, awk

I am learnig AWK, and I am trying to match any word from a file which contain at leas two vowels. My code is

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN{c=0}
{   for(i=1; i<=NF; i++){
        if( match($i,"(.*[aeiou].*){2,}") > 0 )
            c++
    }
}
END{print c}
```

I am actually using, as test file, some random stuff, like

```
asd
e
ef
eseg <seg s<gko<
<sg<se
 eg eg eg 
PEAORJ<ÈMOFEPRIAGÒAJPD<SKAKROPDSAF
foeipsfipiè<+oèipiau
aeiouaeiou
```

I also tested my regex on myregextester.com and there it seems to work.
what am I mistaking?

Comment: What do you mean by "word" (something delimited by spaces? consecutive characters from `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`? other?) and by "vowels" (only `[aeiou]`? Do you want to take accented vowels in account?)?

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: On OS X I get `3`, which seems correct (lines 4, 8, and 9) of your sample, but maybe you're expecting something different?

Comment: Is `y` a vowel in your application? In general it is used as both a vowel and a consonant - see for example http://dictionary.reference.com/help/faq/language/g01.html and http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/words/is-the-letter-y-a-vowel-or-a-consonant.

Comment: Sorry for being not clear enough, by word i mean a string delimited by spaces (like a normal .txt file). by vowels i mean just [aeiou], I am not looking for uppercase letters. In this case i expect 3, as jas obtained, but when i run the code on my ubuntu machine, match() returns 0.  I do not understand what's wrong with the code (if there is something wrong of course)

Answer (score 2):

Your awk script can be refactored (or simplified) to this (gnu-awk):

```
awk -v RS='[[:space:]]+' '/(.*[aeiouAEIOU].*){2}/{c++} END{print c+0}' file
```

It will output:

```
4
```

because to count words with vowels I have also included upper case vowels into character class.

`-v RS='[[:space:]]+'` will split input into records of single word.

Comment: thank you anubhava, it works nicely, but the code i am trying to utilize is part of a homework, so I can't substitute it :)